# Make a button Unclickable from onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I am trying to use Compose and Kotlin in this code to make the button unclickable when counter == 3.
When I run the code and counter presumably is 3, the button stays clickable and wont change to uncklickable.

```
var counter = 0
var isClickable by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

fun QuizScreen (modifier: androidx.compose.ui.Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
  ){
        Button( enabled = isClickable,onClick = {
            if(counter == 3){
                isClickable = false
            }
             
         }
   }

}
```

Tried using remember variable so when I change the variable from onClick, it changes the state of the button, but it still wont change

Answer (score 2):

You can use a condition (`count <3`) for the `enabled` parameter:

```
    var count by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        Text(text = "$count")
        Button(
            enabled = count <3,
            onClick = { count++ }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Count++")
        }
    }
```

In your code `counter` is not incremented and it is not a state and the `Button` is never recomposed.

Comment: Changed "enabled = isClickable" to "enabled = counter <3" and worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun QuizScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

   
    var count by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        Text(text = count.toString())
        Button( enabled = count <3,
        onClick = { count++ }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Count++")
        }
    }
}
```